# Using pointers as values for map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a `map<key_t, struct tr_n_t*> nodeTable` and I'm trying to perform `nodeTable[a] = someNode` where `a` is of type `typedef long key_t` and `someNode` is of type `o_t*`.

I get a segmentation fault at the following point in the execution in stl_function.h:

```
  /// One of the @link comparison_functors comparison functors@endlink.
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct less : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
    {
      bool
      operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
      { return __x < __y; }
    };
```

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef long key_t;

typedef struct tr_n_t {
    key_t key;
    map<key_t, struct tr_n_t *> nodeTable;
} o_t;

int main() {
    o_t *o = (o_t *) malloc(sizeof(o_t));
    o->nodeTable[1] = o;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I not using the map right?

Comment: I face this issue while inserting the very first element in the map.

Comment: Please post more of your code.

Comment: Either you are using the `map` wrong, or there is a bug in your compiler. You should provide a complete example program that exhibits your problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you described, http://ideone.com/DoKevj - please post a minimal compilable failing example

Comment: Could be memory corruption occurring elsewhere in your code. I don't know why posters think we can solve programming problems without seeing the code. Post the code.

Comment: You are using the map right. You have a bug somewhere else in your program. Don't think that just because the code crashes in a map routine that your bug must have something to do with the map. That's a mistake.

Comment: One explanation would be that `ord` is either NULL or garbage when you call `myFunction`.

Comment: If this error occurs when you are inserting the very first element in the map, then it should be quite easy to post a small but complete program that has this problem. Do that and you'll get the answer very quickly.

Comment: @john: Yes, was going to ask if ord is definitely valid at the point that `ord->nodeTable[a] = ord` is called? One way of addressing this would be to move away from raw pointers (i.e. pass `ord` by reference into `myfunction` and use smart pointers as the `nodeTable` value if possible. That should force the issue a bit.

Comment: Wrote a small program that throws the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that because you initialize o using malloc, its memory is allocated but its constructor isn't invoked.

Change it to `o_t *o = new o_t();` because using `new` instead of `malloc` will invoke the map's constructor.

Comment: use replace new to manually invoke constructor: `o = new (o)o_t();` but no point to do that. just use new operator.

Comment: @MintUser, You can but why on earth would you want to? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MintUser You can, yes. To manually invoke the map's constructor, you use a technique called "placement new": https://www.google.ca/search?q=placement+new

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating space for an `o_t`, but you are not initialising the memory. Try this instead:

```
#include <map>

typedef long key_t;

struct o_t {
    key_t key;
    std::map<key_t, o_t*> nodeTable;
};

int main() {
    o_t o;
    o.nodeTable[1] = &o;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a C style `malloc` to allocate a structure that contains a C++ class. No constructor of the `std::map` is called hence the object is invalid. You can't use malloc with plain structures but not on object that require a correct initialization to work.

Try to change allocation to

```
o_t *o = new o_t();
```